# StaleElementReferenceException while trying to move_to_element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to `.click()` a few elements in a pop up-list on a webpage, but keep getting the `StaleElementReferenceException` when i try to move_to_elements.

The code is based around a number of clickable elements in a feed. When clicked, these elements result in a pop-up box with more clickable elements that I want to access.

I access the pop up-box with the following code, where popupbox_links are a list with coordinates and links for the pop up boxes:

```
for coordinate in popupbox_links:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(coordinate["Popupbox location"]).perform()
    time.sleep(3)
    popupboxpath = coordinate["Popupbox link"]
    popupboxpath.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

This works fine. But when the pop up box is opened, I want to perform the following:

```
seemore = driver.find_element_by_link_text("See More") 
time.sleep(2)
actions.move_to_element(seemore).perform()
time.sleep(2)
seemore.click()
time.sleep(3)
findbuttons = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Button")
time.sleep(2)
print(findbutton)
for button in findbuttons:
    time.sleep(2)
    actions.move_to_element(button).perform() 
    time.sleep(2)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
```

The trouble starts at `actions.move_to_element` on both "See more" and "Button". Even though the print(findbutton) actually returns a list with contents, containing the elements that I want to click, Selenium seems to be unable to move_to_element on these. Instead, it throws `StaleElementReferenceException`.

To make it more confusing, the script seems to work at times. Although usually it just crashes.

Any clues on how to solve this? Big thanks in advance.

I'm running the latest Selenium on Python 3.6 with the Chrome WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

**StaleElementReferenceException**  Says that element is stage because something has changed in page after you created the webElement object. In you case that could be happening due to `button.click()`.

The simplest solution is to create new element every time, rather than iterate element from the loop.

following changes might work.

```
findbuttons = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Button")
time.sleep(2)
print(findbuttons)
for i in range(len(findbuttons)):
    time.sleep(2)
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Button")[i]
    actions.move_to_element(elem).perform() 
    time.sleep(2)
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will try it on later. How would you perform it in the first place:

seemore = driver.find_element_by_link_text("See More") 

as here it is not a list of elements to iterate over but just one specific element. And I still get StaleElement when trying to move to it.

Comment: you gotta find out the root cause why you are getting it, in you question it was `clicking on some element`. In this case it could be anything. there is a `Explicit Wait` as well to handle this condition.